# filtering amadeus flightsOffers using carriers code using node js and graphql

Tags: node.js, apollo-server, amadeus

I have to filter the flightOffer using `origin, destination, departureDate, carrier`

but I've got this error message when adding carrier to parametres 
`Some of the parameters were not recognized. Please check your query.`
How can I filter the result by passing carrier to amadeus query ??

the query

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';
import amadeus from './../../../../amadeus';

export default async (parent, args, context, info) => {
  try {
    const { result } = await amadeus.shopping.flightOffers.get({
      origin: args.filter.origin,
      destination: args.filter.destination,
      departureDate: args.filter.departureDate,
      carrier: args.filter.carrier
    });
    context.dictionaries =await result.dictionaries;
    return result.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    Sentry.captureException(error);
    return [];
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code it is not clear if you use the [Flight Low-fare Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-low-fare-search/api-reference) or the [Flight Offers Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference).

In any case, those 2 APIs do not have a carrier parameter. If you want to filter by airlines you can use:

For **Flight Low-fare Search**:

- includeAirlines: List of airline IATA codes to include, comma-separated
- excludeAirlines: List of airline IATA codes to exclude, comma-separated

For **Flight Offers Search**:

- includedAirlineCodes: List of airline IATA codes to include, comma-separated
- excludedAirlineCodes: List of airline IATA codes to exclude, comma-separated

Comment: Thank you very much this helps but in node js how can I use [Flight Offers Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference)
I've seen just [Flight Low-fare Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-low-fare-search/api-reference)

Comment: We released a new version of the API (Flight Offers Search) which will be the v2 of Flight Low-fare Search. You can find more information here: developers.amadeus.com/blog/…. Flight Low-fare Search has not been decommissioned yet as the version 2 is still in beta. The SDK will be updated when the version 2 becomes the official new version.

Comment: Is that feature available yet? I can't find includedAirlinesCodes or excluded in flight offers documentation. I was trying with CarrierRestrictions, but I need to exclude by Operator.